# AWS EC2 Ubuntu Instance run microsoft teams

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, microsoft-teams

I have launched an m6i.large instance of AWS Ec2 using ubuntu server 20.04 LTS image and General Purpose SSD EBS of 30GB. For RDP, I have installed xrdp and xfce4.

When I'm trying to connect to Microsoft teams call from the instance, I'm not able to hear anything, and the video is also lagging.

Can anyone please help me understand what configuration I need to use Microsoft teams on AWS EC2 Ubuntu instance successfully?

Comment: Can you share what you have followed ? Any doc or any sample you are trying to set it up?

Comment: I have seen Microsoft docs on [hardware requirement for Microsoft teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/hardware-requirements-for-the-teams-app). In the docs, it is mentioned that at least 4GB of dedicated RAM is required for Microsoft teams, and in my device, I have 8GB RAM, and I do heavy computing, but teams work without lagging, so I assume 8GB of EC2 will be enough. Hence, I have chosen m6i.large as the instance type.

Comment: Also, I have followed Microsft docs on [Install and configure xrdp to use Remote Desktop with Ubuntu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/use-remote-desktop) to enable RDP on my Ubuntu instance.